# Insert into table using select plus value?

Tags: sql, teradata

I created a table modeled on an existing table:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
(SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE record_status = 'xyz' ) WITH DATA;
```

I then added a column:

```
ALTER TABLE new_table ADD new_column VARCHAR(100);
```

I now want to select more rows from the old table into the new table, but add a fixed value (eg. `'blabla'`) to the new column for each row selected. I tried a bunch of things, such as:

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT *, 'blabla'
FROM old_table)
WHERE is_blabla = 'Y'
```

Tried every permutation I could think of but keep getting syntax errors. Any suggestions? I'm using Teradata.

- Dave

Comment: The optimizer assumes all columns for `*` and is confused when you want more than all :-)  E.g. Oracle works the same way, you must alias the table and then use `myalias.*`.

Comment: Use `old_table.*` instead of just `*` or alias your table and use the alias as @dnoeth suggested. This is just a technical limitation of TD and not a logical limitation. SQL Server for instance have no issues with `select *,'blabla'` or `select *,*,*`

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO new_table 
SELECT old_table.*,'your_fixed_value'
FROM   old_table 
WHERE  is_blabla='Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to alias your table

INSERT INTO new_table 
SELECT a.*,'your_fixed_value'
FROM   old_table a
WHERE  is_blabla='Y'